# select for update and php scripts

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Does select for update pause a php script until the data can be returned?
for example

```
$result=select * from blah for update;
$blah=$row['...'];
echo $blah
```

will $blah echo even if the sql query is still in the queue for the select or will the script wait until it can select before it echo's?

Comment: if the select paused the script, then there'd be no way for the script to "unpause" by fetching data, because it's been paused. What the select will do is prevent any OTHER parallel db requests from proceeding. The script will pause while the query is actually running, but once there's data to be returned, php will resume.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for wanting something non-blocking? Do you have a slow-performing query, for example? That is often a problem that can be solved.

Comment: i would like it to be blocking. my understanding is there is a queue for the select for update which processes the request serially preventing parallel requests. under this select i have other functions that will run but rely on the data returned by the select. just need to know that the script will pause until select can pull data..

Answer (score 0):

This is blocking.

If you are looking for non-blocking code, you should check at node.js which uses callbacks for when the query actually returns something.

Comment: It's quite a leap from here to node.js. Kind of like saying "Your car only works on the road. You should try a helicopter."

Comment: Well if you need to get in the air, I won't put some turbojet on your car just so you are happy with the answer.

Comment: Nor would I, but my point is (and I admit I didn't state it) that we should find out what the OP's need is before confusing the issue with unrelated platforms.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i would like this to be blocking. basically the php script waits until data is returned from the select then continuing down the flow off the script.. is this correct?